# Why using display table for vertical align is bad practice

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have read a lot of different articles about available methods for vertical centering using CSS.
I understand how everything works, but I have found a lot of phrases like layout using tables is considered bad practice ?

I found that using `display : table` is supported by most of the old browsers, even mobile browsers like `Opera Mini` for antique phones.

Please explain why is it considered bad practice to use divs with `display : table` and what is the most well-supported way to align vertically than.

Thx.

Comment: "layout using tables" and "layout using `display: table`" are not the same thing; your question seems to be based on a false premise.

Comment: @Quentin Layout using `display:table` is abuse of tables too; you're just using different tag names.

Comment: @MrLister — No. Table elements come with semantics that describe a relationship between bits of data. Table CSS is presentation.

Comment: Is it ok to use `display:table` , I have searched and found that is the most well supported method. All others like flex, transform are available only in new browsers. Also there is another well supported method is using `before` with inline elements.