# Display: table-cell; adding extra space on left of text

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to html and css have been kind of struggling to get my text aligned vertically next to an image using css and html.

I came across a nice solution using "display: table-cell;" in the

class and "display: table;" in it's container class.

This seemed to work until I came across a case where my text didn't spill over to a second line. For whatever reason, it seems my text which the shorter sentence is aligned to the center of the space between the image and the next column.

Html:

```
<h3 class="red-header">
  Buttons Header
</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column divLink">
    <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <p class="icon-text">
      <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 1</span>
      <br /> short line extra space on the left</p>
    <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column divLink">
    <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <p class="icon-text">
      <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 2</span>
      <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered</p>
    <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column divLink">
    <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <p class="icon-text">
      <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 3</span>
      <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered</p>
    <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column divLink">
    <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
    <p class="icon-text">

      <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 4</span>


      <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered </p>
    <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red-header {
  background-color: #be1e2d;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: .6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-text {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.red-text {
  color: #be1e2d;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.icon-img {
  float: left;
  width: 115px;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 0px;
}

.feature {
  position: relative;
}

/* used to make entire div into a clickable element */
.feature {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* No underlines on the link */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
}

/* visualization of the button using a hover */
.divLink:hover {
  background-color: #b1e3e6;
}
```

My apologies for a terrible explanation, [please see the following fiddle for clarity.](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lp507cw/4/) Issue is in the "Button Text pt 1"

Comment: A bit of advice if you are just learning: It is bad practice to use `display: table` on anything that is not an actual table. You should probably learn with methods that are more modern such as using `display: flex` (flexbox)  for example. flexbox makes it very easy to create columns, center horizontally and vertically, and a bunch of other cool stuff.  Check out this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn about the flexbox capabilities to see if it is right for you.

Comment: @Matthew Appreciate your quick reply. In my research it seems there are mixed opinions about using display: table as a means of presentation. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619180/why-using-display-table-for-vertical-align-is-bad-practice comments in this question seem to make a distinction between using a table html tags vs using display: table for layout/presentation purposes.

Obviously, this user isn't the end all be all, but I have come across a number of opinions that are similar to this. Am I misinterpreting this response?

Comment: No I do not think you are misinterpreting those comments. Really it is all about personal preference. Technically it is ok to use `display: table` for non table related things, but the only justification seems to be that older browsers support it. The real answer to the question would be what demographic are you developing for? Should your users have up-to-date browsers? and do you want to include older browsers that aren't even supported by their developers anymore as an option for your users?

Comment: My opinion is we developers should not support browsers that are out-dated just because people don't like change. Other people will disagree with me though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix the spacing issue you are having with your current code by adding the following `width: 100%` to the `.icon-text` class:

```
.icon-text {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Of course I still recommend you go with flexbox instead.

Comment: Wow. Embarrassing how simple that oversight was. And yes, I will definitely look into flexbox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whoever down-voted all the answers. Please put a comment under each one explaining the down-vote. My answer resolved the OP's issue and our conversion encouraged him to look into more modern methods. sooo.. Explain yourself.

Comment: @nonForMe please mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your issue so the ticket can be complete.

Comment: Yeah. I was confused about this as well. I don't know much about stackoverflow posting or down/upvote meta so I found this somewhat bizarre. 

Especially considering you gave me some good perspective and i7nvd even provided a slight change using flexbox.

Anyway, appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

Is this closer to what you were looking for? `display: table` should only be used for tables, which this isn't. You want Flexbox!

https://jsfiddle.net/o092e0y9/

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution with what you have now

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lp507cw/5/

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="red-header">
  Buttons Header
</h3>
<div class="table">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column divLink">
      <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
      <p class="icon-text">
        <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 1</span>
        <br /> short line extra space on the left</p>
      <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column divLink">
      <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
      <p class="icon-text">
        <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 2</span>
        <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered</p>
      <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column divLink">
      <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
      <p class="icon-text">
        <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 3</span>
        <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered</p>
      <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column divLink">
      <img class="icon-img" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" />
      <p class="icon-text">

        <span class="red-text">Button Text pt 4</span>


        <br /> short setence describing button could possibly extend for a line or two or three. Would like this to be centered </p>
      <a class="feature" href="google.ca"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red-header {
  background-color: #be1e2d;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: .6rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.table{width:100%; display:table;}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display:table-row;
}

.icon-text {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  width:70%;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

.red-text {
  color: #be1e2d;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.icon-img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 0px;
}

.feature {
  position: relative;
}

.feature {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* No underlines on the link */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
}

.divLink:hover {
  background-color: #b1e3e6;
}
```